# Access To Withdrawal Reason in Withdraw Event

Tags: balances

I am developing a pallet that uses an off-chain worker to aggregate and store transaction fee data on a per-block basis.

To do this, the most reasonable implementation looks to be using [Withdraw events](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0ba251c9388452c879bfcca425ada66f1f9bc802/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L1706) (and crediting any extra withdrawn fees that are refunded) in a given block. However, there is no clear way to differentiate between Withdraw events for transaction fees and Withdraw events for other reasons.

Would it be reasonable to expose the [Event Reason](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0ba251c9388452c879bfcca425ada66f1f9bc802/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L630) in the Balances Event? If not, is there a feasible workaround to filter Withdraw events by type?

Comment: What are the possible "withdraw reasons" that you would want to include?

Comment: I just need access as to whether or not the withdraw event was from a Transaction Fee, so the existing [Reasons enum](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0ba251c9388452c879bfcca425ada66f1f9bc802/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L628-L635) would suffice for my purpose. It looks like it may be difficult (depending on the subsequent events) to parse the transaction fee from a Withdrawal with [Reasons::All](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0ba251c9388452c879bfcca425ada66f1f9bc802/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L641), but if I understand correctly, that would be a small minority of txns.

Comment: I don't think we would add this information in this way. For this specific scenario, the best suggestion would be an event specific to transaction payment pallet which specifically emits the fee taken. Beyond that, I have written some code which tries to track fees, and what I end up doing is look at the deposit events for the block author and the treasury, which combined, is the total fee taken for that extrinsic.

Comment: Makes sense. The better ask is probably adding an event to the txn payment pallet as you mention. The problem with looking at the treasury/block author deposit events specifically is that while it may work for a majority of existing chains, this fee logic is customizable and thus not generalizable for all substrate chains